# Elimination of weakly dominated strategies - example

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I am supposed to solve a game by iterated elimination of weakly dominated strategies:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
& L & C & R \\ \hline
T & 2, 1 & 1, 1 & 0, 0 \\ \hline
M & 1, 2 & 3, 1 & 2, 1 \\ \hline
B & 2, -2 & 1, -1 & -1, -1
\end{array}
$$
But I can not find any weakly dominated strategy for any player. $R$ comes close, but $(B, L)$ is worse for player $2$ than $(B, R)$. So, is there any way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: $B$ is weakly dominated by $T$

Step 2: $R$ is weakly dominated by $C$

Step 3: $C$ is weakly dominated by $L$

Step 4: $M$ is weakly dominated by $T$

So the NE you end up with is $(T,L)$. However,  remember that iterated elimination of weakly (not strict) dominant strategies can rule out some NE.

Comment: Okay, thanks, now I understand. But how is $(B, L)$ a NE? Wouldn't player $2$ be better off by switching to $C$ or $L$?

Comment: My bad you are right. Sorry I wrote the answer on my phone. Have just corrected it.